# cURL shows different html then what is rendered in the browser

Tags: php, html, curl

I trying to get data from a remote site with cUrl but the text what I see in the screen not appear in the returned source code.

Example.

I see:

> $9.99 USD

The true html is: `<span class="any" id="price">$9.99 USD</span>`

The returned html with cUrl is: `<span class="any" id="price">{price}</span>`

I have tried many cUrl options and the result is always the same.

Comment: Is that target HTML page using some sort of javascript functionality to replace the tags like `{price}` with `$9.99 USD`?

Comment: Looks like something a library like Angular would do, where it is waiting for an event to populate the price. Not sure you will be able to get the price using curl. Have you looked into trying to do this with JavaScript instead?

Answer (score 0):

From [cURL FAQs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Does_curl_support_Javascript_or)

> Many web pages do magic stuff using embedded Javascript. Curl and libcurl have no built-in support for that, so it will be treated just like any other contents.

And if you still want to go down this same path:

> Implement a Javascript interpreter, people have successfully used the
>   Mozilla Javascript engine in the past

Comment: I'm not sure for this. I'm using Mozilla Firefox explorer with Javascript enabled on my desktop and when taking "view page source" I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Is the URL public? Can i test it? Could it be possible that the URL needs login (or subsequently cookies to be send along with the `cURL` request)?

Comment: in this case the returned code is ><span class="currency-adjust"><span class="price">{0}</span>/<span class="period">{1}</span></span>

Comment: Found it! Go to source code, and check line 246! There is the javascript code which is being used to change the currency based on some parameters. In the end, it is some javascript which is being used! `tokenizedHtml = html.replace(/\{0\}/gi, val);` This replaces the "{0}" and the next line uses some `jQuery` to set that into the DOM.

Comment: But... how I could get this data with cUrl?

Comment: That is what my answer says. You need to parse HTML for Javascript. Hence, a javascript interpreter.

Comment: What do you recommend for my server with Centos 6.5 and php 5.3.3,?

Comment: You don't need server side javascript for this. I think you should clarify your concepts first.